# Why doesn't this function give window.alert when user enters spaces or too many/not enough characthers?

Tags: javascript, html

Seemed like an easy problem to solve. Cannot figure out why the code will return the secret word despite entering spaces or too many/too few characters. Need a little help. Thanx!

```
function secretWord() {
        var text = "You entered";
        var output = "Thank you, Po's secret word was validated";
        <!--variable to hold secret word-->          
        var user_prompt = prompt("Enter Allen's secret word. It must contain exactly 7 characters and there can be no empty spaces", "");

            do {
                if(user_prompt.length == 6 && user_prompt.indexOf('') >= 0) {
                document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML= text + "<br>" + user_prompt + "<br>" + output;
                }   
                    else if(user.prompt.length < 6) {
                        window.alert("secret word is too short");
                        var user_prompt;
                        document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML= text + "<br>" + user_prompt + "<br>" + output;

                        }
                        else if(user.prompt.length > 6) {
                            window.alert("secret word is too long")
                            var user_prompt;
                            document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML= text + "<br>" + user_prompt + "<br>" + output;
                            }
                            else if(user_prompt.indexOf('') >= 0) {
                            window.alert("secret word cannot contain spaces");
                            var user_prompt;
                            document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML= text + "<br>" + user_prompt + "<br>" + output;

                            }
                }
                while(user_prompt != -999);
    }
```

Comment: `<!--variable to hold secret word--> ` is this in your code, or just for the example here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apart from the typos you have (`user_prompt != user.prompt`), you're looking for a 7-character string with no spaces.

What this condition checks:

```
if(user_prompt.length == 6 && user_prompt.indexOf('') >= 0) {
```

is a 6-character string with ANY character present.

What you need instead is:

```
if(user_prompt.length == 7 && user_prompt.indexOf(' ') == -1) {
```

This will be true if the string length is 7 and there are no spaces.

---

Here's a working example, I've simplified it a bit so it's easier to work with in a snippet here, but you can see and reuse the conditions:

```js
function secretWord() {
  var text = "You entered";
  var output = "Thank you, Po's secret word was validated";
  var user_prompt = prompt("Enter Allen's secret word. It must contain exactly 7 characters and there can be no empty spaces", "");

  document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML = '';
  
  if (user_prompt.length == 7 && user_prompt.indexOf(' ') == -1) {
    document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML = text + "<br>" + user_prompt + "<br>" + output;
  } else if (user_prompt.length < 7) {
    document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML = "secret word is too short";
  } else if (user_prompt.length > 7) {
    document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML = "secret word is too long";
  } else if (user_prompt.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("guess").innerHTML = "secret word cannot contain spaces";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="guess"></div>
<button onclick="secretWord()">Run</button>
```

Comment: @allendks45, the strings do start at 0, you're right. But you're checking string length here, not the value at string[6] - so length of 0 means it's an empty string, length of 1 it's a 1-character string... and finally length of 7 means it's a 7-character string.

Answer (score 2):

```
else if(user.prompt.length < 6) {
// ...
else if(user.prompt.length > 6) {
```

In both cases, `user.prompt.length` should be `user_prompt.length`

Answer (score 2):

your problem is in else if statement

it should be `user_prompt` and not `user.prompt`

besides, even if you enter space yet exactly right amount of characters say 6 or so, it will pass the first if test.
you are not checking for space i.e. `' '` but `''`. see to it you check for spaces properly.

Comment: I apologize and see the stupid simple mistakes. Been up too long and should have worked on this later. I also thought characters in a string start at 0 making the count comparison 6. Is this not correct? Thanks for the comments and assistance.

Comment: indexing starts from 0 that's correct. but you use index when you are accessing the elements/characters of the string. to access the first element you will use index 0. but length property is something that tells you how many characters are present in the string/array. For ex. a string has one character, so to access that character you'll need to use index that is character at 0th  location, but length is 1. you can say the string has 0 length as it contains 1 character which can be accessed with index 0. makes sense?!! :)

Comment: Yes, definitely. Better explanation than the book. If the code were written to reflect the individual elements it would have been '6'. Great! learned a bit more today.